# VBA Excel | Filter multuple columns based on single value

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Goodday, I am kinda stuck at a problem with filtering.
To put it in pseudo code I want to achieve the following:

```
general_condition, condition1, condition2, condition3, etc...

if(any_column_contains(general_condition) OR
    (column(1).contains(condition1) AND
     column(2).contains(condition2) AND
     column(3).contains(condition3) AND
     ... etc.))
    Include row;
else
    Exclude row;
```

I know you can use .AutoFilter on a range, and pass in an array to 'criteria1' (and 'Field') to filter multiple columns and conditions, but I can't seem to find a way to combine the 'AND' and 'OR' operator described in the example above. I tried using the xlOr operator in combination with an array, but it doesnt work that way (I suspect that only works when combining the 'criteria1' and 'criteria2' parameter).

Any help/hints are appreciated

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a helper column? Put your evaluation there and filter on it.

Comment: Would be possible indeed. How would you filter the first part then? (the 'any_column_contains' part)?

Comment: With something like `=FIND("something",CONCAT(A2:F2))>0`